# Integrate SNES Game Emulator with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-emulator, game-engine

I am trying to integrate SNES game emulator library into Android Studio, but there are few files are missing or not supported with latest NDK versions.

I have tried following all libraries but didnt get success to load and start emulator.
[image]

So is there anyone here who can give idea about how to achieve any of the SNES emulator integration with Android Studio.

Thanks